# Two different providers from Database

Tags: symfony, security

My problem is that I want to use 2 different user-types "Familia" and "Doctor" I configure the security.yml this way:

```
providers: 




    client_db:
        entity: 
          class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Familia
          property: email

    manager_db:
        entity: 
          class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Doctor
          property: email
```

The problem is that I can login with Familia, but if I try to login with doctor, it returns me "Bad Credentials". Both entities have

```
 class Doctor implements UserInterface
 {
 public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_DOC');
}

public function getSalt()

{
    return false;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $user->getUsername() == $this->getUsername();
}
```

Here goes my security file.

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512

    Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Familia: 
      algorithm: plaintext

    Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Doctor:
      algorithm: plaintext




providers: 
  chain_provider:
    chain:
      providers: [user_db, admin_db]



      user_db:
        entity: 
          class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Familia
          property: email

      admin_db:
        entity: 
          class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Doctor
          property: email

firewalls:

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /check
            login_path: /login
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /checking

            use_referer:                    false
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/familia, roles: ROLE_FAM }
    - { path: ^/doctor, roles: ROLE_DOC}
```

questions:

- Is the security code part well written? Is there something left?
- Do I have to add something in the entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is chaining your providers as follow :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [client_db, manager_db]
        client_db:
            entity: 
                class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Familia
                property: email

        manager_db:
            entity: 
                class: Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Doctor
                property: email
```

This will try the login process first with the client provider, then with the manager one, and if both fail it will tell you some kind of "bad credentials" error.

Comment: Looks like it is starting to work but now I have this error: InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "providers, client_db, manager_db" under "security.providers.chain_provider"

Comment: You are missing the `chain` config tree node in between. 
`security` -> `providers` -> `my_chain_provider_foo_bar` -> `chain` -> `providers: [client_db, manager_db]`

Comment: That seems quite odd. The doc says exactly it here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-multiple-user-providers . What version of Symfony do you use?

Comment: Still having the same error but now: ** Unrecognized options " client_db, manager_db" under "security.providers.chain_provider"**

Comment: According to the doc, there is no need to add tree config nodes here as it's part of the current version. But if you're using an old one you could have problems Droyo. Can you tell us which version of SF2 you are using please?

Comment: Hmm that's odd, did you try to copy / paste the code I wrote previously? (I've updated it to match what you post before)

Comment: If I copy/paste ur code it gives me the error : InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "providers, client_db, manager_db" under "security.providers.chain_provider". According to "the book" i have to add "chain" but adding chain it returns me the error: nrecognized options " client_db, manager_db" under "security.providers.chain_provider

Comment: Can you then please copy / paste in your original post your whole security.yml file, obfuscating your sensitive data of cource :)

Comment: I have posted my security.yml file

Comment: Isn't there an identation problem? As providers , encoders, etc are on the same level of the "security" word? Or is it a copy / paste matter?

Adding the "chain" is for SF2 versions <2.2

Comment: It is copy paste matter. There are two things that happen, if I dont add the chain, it logs against the first provider, the other gives bad credentials. If I add the chain_provider The error that returns is Unrecognized options for chain_provider

Comment: I think I made a typo mistake in my first post. Just edited it now, can you try using my last update? (there was a missing "chain" under "chain_provider" ..... :-( )

Comment: Error returned  Unrecognized options "client_db, manager_db" under "security.providers.chain_provider.chain" This is realy annoying

Comment: AH!!I get it!! It's normal => you have there a bad indentation in your security.yml file => user_db and admin_db are at the same level as "providers" whereas they should be at the same level as "chain_provider" as shown in my example :)

Comment: OK @YoannCh Your answer is correct. The problem, If you can see it in my code, was that `user_db` and `admin_db`have to be at the same tab than `chain_provider` what a stupid thing

Comment: Nice that helped you Droyo. That's because I saw the problem in your code snippet that I suggested that there was an indentation error on that level. :) Glad it helped!